# How to add google ads interstitial in PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, admob

How to add the Google ads interstitial in my Phone Gap project.
Please send me link or example for reference.

Comment: Please update your question with your code which you have tried.

Comment: Quite easy, if you wanna try: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro

Comment: thanks it's working for me....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the following link and find the demo to add Interstitial ads in phone gap.

github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro